# Asynchronously getting data in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a label that shows the name of user who is logged in:

```
 <p style="color:white;font-weight:bolder;font-size:20px;padding-left:15px" title="Enter">{{userName}}  Welcome</p>
```

In my controller I checked if the the user was authenticated:

```
$scope.initial = function () {
        $http.get('Accounts/UserIsAuthenticated').success(function (response) {
            // Accounts/UserIsAuthenticated check whether user is authenticated or not, and return bool value
            debugger;
            if (response == 'True') {
                $rootScope.showLogin = false;
                $rootScope.showWelcome = true;
                $scope.userName = getUserName();
                $rootScope.showLogout = true;

            }
            else {
                $rootScope.showLogin = true;
                $rootScope.showWelcome = false;
                $rootScope.showLogout = false;
            }

        });
    };
     function getUserName() {
        $http.get('Accounts/GetUserName').success(function (response) {
            return response;
        });
    }
```

`{{userName}}` is being set to `undefined` though. I know that `getUserName()` needs time for response, so how can I fix it?

Edit: I edit my code :

```
$scope.initial = function () {
        $http.get('Accounts/UserIsAuthenticated').success(function (response) {
            if (response == 'True') {
                $rootScope.showLogin = false;
                $rootScope.showWelcome = true;
                getUserName().then(function (username) {
                    debugger;
                    $scope.username = username;
                });

                $rootScope.showLogout = true;

            }
            else {
                $rootScope.showLogin = true;
                $rootScope.showWelcome = false;
                $rootScope.showLogout = false;
            }

        });
    };

    function getUserName() {
        $http.get('Accounts/GetUserName');

    }
```

But it does not work! what is the problem?

Comment: the `return` in this code won't really return anything.  It's inside the callback function, which can't return anything.  It's not inside the `getUserName` function, which would be able to return something, but moving it there doesn't help.  In general, when dealing with async methods, you **don't** return the *value*, you **do** return the *promise* that there will be a value later. (`return $http.get( ... `in this example).

Answer (score 1):

Change your getUsername to this:

```
function getUserName() {
    // return the promise
    return $http.get('Accounts/GetUserName');
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
if (response == 'True') {
    $rootScope.showLogin = false;
    $rootScope.showWelcome = true;
    // use the promise
    getUserName().then(function(username){
        $scope.username = username;
    });
    $rootScope.showLogout = true;
}
```

Or, just change your getUsername to this:

```
function setUserName() {
    $http.get('Accounts/GetUserName').success(function (response) {
        $scope.username = response;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I got an error : `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Comment: you have to return the `$http` call, see the first function in my answer

Comment: You need to add the return call in getUserName like what @devqon said